# Filtering cards into appropriate list elements

Tags: c#

**Background:**

I have two lists: one with a list of workcentres and the other with a list of the stations in the centres.

This code matches the stations to the centres by comparing the stations' workcentre number property with the name property of the centres.

```
    private void WsSorter(WorkcentreList wcl, List<WorkstationCard> wscl)
    {
        // Find index of workcentres
        foreach (Workcentre wc in wcl.WcList)
        {
            foreach (WorkstationCard wsc in wscl)
            {
                if (!(wsc.WorkcentreNo == MAIN_WORKCENTRE_1 ||
                 wsc.WorkcentreNo == MAIN_WORKCENTRE_2 ||
                 wsc.WorkcentreNo == MAIN_WORKCENTRE_3 ))
                {
                    wc.CardList.Add(wsc); // Must be adding to "Other WC"
                }
                // Add to matching workcentre
                else if (wsc.WorkcentreNo == wc.WcName) 
                {
                    wc.CardList.Add(wsc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question**

The lint tool I am using, `SonarLint` is telling me off for violating the DRY principle in the `else if` condition.

It works, albeit with poor error checking but I would like to know, is there a better way I could write the code / approach the situation, especially regarding not repeating the line `wc.CardList.Add(wsc);`?

Additional context: There are 3 main workcentres. All other workcentres (of which there is an arbitrary amount) should be classified under 'other'. I set the code up such that if the stations don't belong to a main workcentre, it must belong in the 'other' workcentre.

Comment: You are not sorting.  You are filtering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- By simply adding the `else` condition to the `if`, the DRY warning will go away. It's just telling you that both the `if` and `else` block currently execute the same code, and can therefore be consolidated into a single block.
- The comment `// Find index of workcentres` is misleading and should be removed.
- Don't use abbreviations for naming. It makes it very hard to read and understand the code.
- By extracting the condition to a separate method, you can use the `Where()` LINQ method and call `AddRange()` instead of repeatedly calling `Add()` .
- Like @Paparazzi mentioned in a comment, you are *filtering*, rather than sorting, so you should change the name of the method.

Implementing the changes (except for the naming), you code will look like the following:

```
private void WsSorter(WorkcentreList wcl, List<WorkstationCard> wscl)
{
    foreach (Workcentre wc in wcl.WcList)
    {
        wc.CardList.AddRange(wscl.Where(workstationCard => IsDesiredWorkstationCard(workstationCard, wc.WcName)));
    }
}
private bool IsDesiredWorkstationCard(WorkstationCard workstationCard, string workCentreName)
{
    return !(workstationCard.WorkcentreNo == MAIN_WORKCENTRE_1 ||
             workstationCard.WorkcentreNo == MAIN_WORKCENTRE_2 ||
             workstationCard.WorkcentreNo == MAIN_WORKCENTRE_3 ) ||
             workstationCard.WorkcentreNo == workCentreName
}
```

Comment: I agree in general about not over-using abbreviations, but do you really think that `wc` is a bad name for a temporary variable with the type `Workcentre`? I don't. There are only two things that I see in need of renaming in this code: the parameters to the `WsSorter` function and the SCREAMING_CAPS names for the constants.

Answer (score 4):

Naming is important.

- `WsSorter` is far too vague.
- Do not needlessly abbreviate: `wcl`, `wscl`. Ditto for the "No" in `WorkcentreNo`. Ditto for the "Wc" in `WcList` and `WcName`.
- The various parts of compound words like `Workcentre` and `Workstation` should be properly capitalized, thus `WorkCentre` and `WorkStation`.
- Maybe it's me, but "centre"? Admittedly, it is [correct in some cases](http://grammarist.com/spelling/center-centre/), but here it feels out of place.
- I don't like the name `WorkcentreList`; moreover, why can't it simple be a `List<WorkCenter>`? Same for `WcList`. Same for `CardList`. Call them `WorkCenters` and `Cards`.
- Constants should be PascalCase: `MAIN_WORKCENTRE_1`.
- I'm a bit confused by the term `WorkcentreNo` (or `WorkCenterNumber` as it perhaps should be). Is this a number, or actually a name?
- Why is `WcName` prefixed with "Wc", considering it is a property of the `WorkCenter` class?

---

Quite frankly I find this to be very convoluted and hard to maintain:

```
if (!(wsc.WorkcentreNo == MAIN_WORKCENTRE_1 ||
wsc.WorkcentreNo == MAIN_WORKCENTRE_2 ||
wsc.WorkcentreNo == MAIN_WORKCENTRE_3 ))
```

What if you need to add another, e.g. `MAIN_WORKCENTRE_4`?

As Heslacher's answer shows: move this to a separate method, and consider moving `MAIN_WORKCENTRE_1` etc. to a collection of "valid" WorkCenterNumbers, thus reducing the code to:

```
private bool IsDesiredWorkstationCard(WorkStationCard workStationCard, string workCenterNumber)
{
    return !(validWorkCenterNumbers.Contains(workStationCard.WorkCenterNumber))
        || workStationCard.WorkCenterNumber == workCenterNumber;
}
```

This could/should perhaps even move to a static class.